# How to add OSGI bundle to JBOSS AS 7.1.1.Final

Tags: osgi, eclipselink, jboss7.x

I'm trying to add OSGI bundles to JBOSS AS 7.1.1.Final. Does this even make sense? The bundles I'm trying to add are: [EclipseLink 2.4.0 OSGi Bundles Zip](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/). Is there an easy way to do this?

I'm guessing that I could probably create modules entries for every jar but that doesn't seem like the right thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since JBoss itself is developed on top of Apache Felix: Yes there is an easy way ;) Just start your JBoss Instance (Standalone):

1. go to the administration webpage (mostly localhost:8080)
2. under *Runtime Operations* click on *OSGi*
3. if you will be asked whether to start OSGi or not, start it. if you already have you will see your whole bunch of installed bundles
4. now copy your bundle you want to add to your JBoss instance
5. now go to your JBoss home folder choose folder *jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments* and paste your copied bundle into it
6. your bundle will be deployed at the moment you pasted it into the folder per hotdeploy

Maybe you already noticed that the main steps (deploying 4-6) are the same steps as you deploy war files. Deploying is also pissible via the administration page.

Comment: Ha - If I thought it was that easy I probably would have figured it out myself. Thanks!